# How to write VS Code extension that folds specific regions and renders an inline summary of the folded region?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In the source code of this project that I'm working on we have big chunks of JSX to localize strings, so instead of having e.g.:

```
<section>
  lore impsum sit amet
</section>
```

we have:

```
<section>
  <SomeCustomWrapper props="X">
    <AnotherWrapper
      message="lorem impsum sit amet"
      description={{
        text: "description for lore impsum sit amet",
        someMoreProps: "X"
      }}
    />
  </SomeCustomWrapper>
</section>
```

I want to write a VS code plugin to "fold/unfold" those SomeCustomWrappers so that the editor displays those tags when folded as, e.g.:

```
<section>
  <string: "lorem impsum sit amet">
</section>
```

But I'm not sure if it's possible given VS Code API, and if it's possible, do you have any hints on how to accomplish it?

Comment: https://github.com/zokugun/vscode-explicit-folding can fold by regex, but you can't do the custom summary string.